# How to control network access of applications by java?

Tags: java, networking

At the moment I am using LittleSnitch, but I was interested in how to create an app in java that controls internet access in runtime or restricts, allows to the specific application at all. And monitor all network connections like in WireShark.

When I googled I could found almost nothing suitable. I doubt that there is any ready project or open source one. So I am very curious about this.

What library should I use? Or do I need to use some JNI libraries to create this kind of application in java?

Comment: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Comment: Java is the wrong tool for this.  The solution will be OS specific, require admin-level access and ... may be technically challenging for some OSes.

Comment: @StephenC But I hoped there are some access to the native method of OS by JNI

Comment: Sure, *for which operating system?*

Comment: @EJP For all. e.g. for Windows I think there should be JNI with dll's, and for Linux .so files